# How to get current frames as image from camera?

Tags: android

Hello im trying to make my own special custom code scanner. My app's render a special custom barcode and I need to make a very simple scanner that will take whats currently being seen with the camera and quickly process it to decode the barcode. So how can I grab the frames from the camera and use them as images without pressing the "take" button.

Answer (score 0):

check the open source project. It give bar-code without click take photo button.

[Link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

Thanks